# Pjax Working on Select Pages Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, pjax

I have seen this asked before on here but couldn't use the suggested solution to fix my issue.
Basically I have implemented the rails pjax gem for a site I am working on, however it only works on some of the content. The home page, and initial level of links down do not load in a pjax-y way, however every subsequent page does.

This is the only place the yield is declared for the site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

      <title>MyWellbeing.org - What's on your mind?</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
      <%= raw "<link href='http://#{request.env["HTTP_HOST"]}/sites/site_styles.css'  media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="container">
        <div id="clicked_off_div" class="display_none"></div>

        <%= render 'articles/shared_article_header' %>
        <%= render 'articles/logged_in' if user_signed_in? %>

        <div data-pjax-container>
          <%= yield %>
        </div>

        <%= render 'articles/shared_footer' %>

      </div>

      <%= render 'shared/google_analytics' %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the link to the working site http://core.giffordteam.com EDIT: PUSHED TO LIVE SITE

Any pointers on this matter would be greatly appreciated. It is very confusing how some, but not all, pages are working.

Thank you

Comment: It's impossible to say without the final html, but `<div onclick="location.href='articles/sad';">` probably bypasses pjax, so that's one thing to look at. It should be fairly simple to debug - just remember to turn on `persist` in firebug's network panel (not sure if other browsers have an equivalent).

Comment: Hello again Sean. I'm about to push it to the live site if this will help. I've noticed in my server panel that the requests for the non-working pages don't have the usual Started GET "/?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" style request, just the standard Started GET "/articles/hungry". I'm not sure what this suggests?
With persists on (thanks for the tip) I get an aborted request GET core.giffordteam.com/articles/… jquery.js?body=1 (line 8103). What can this be an indication of? I shall look at that onclick thing to see if this helps. Thanks

Comment: Ok I fixed the onclick and pushed but it didn't solve the issue, and some other pages now seem to have the abort problem. I have read that maybe the render format in the controller could be the problem? Here is a typical excerpt. def index
    ATarticle_relationships = ArticleRelationship.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: ATarticle_relationships }
    end
  end also I do not know if it is true, but my local version seems to be working through the pjax way, but my server does not. But maybe firebug can't detect errors locally?

Comment: Ok seems to have fully fixed it. I changed the default time out to "$.pjax.defaults.timeout = false;" Also combined with your onclick suggestion the whole thing now seems to work.

Comment: Good job debugging those two issues. You should write an answer and accept it so that it is more obvious to future viewers of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by removing a div's onclick functionality and putting it within a separate anchor tag. I then removed the default timeout for the pjax call with

> $.pjax.defaults.timeout = false;

These combined fixed the issue.

Throughout I used Firebug in Firefox with Persist in the Console turned on. This gave a better indication of consistent fails on certain pages, and also when pages didn't fail what the data should look like.

Massive thank you to Sean Hogan on helping me with this issue. Especially the use of Firebug for debugging.

Comment: This worked for me too. I was getting a page reload every 3-4 attempts. But adding this line stopped the reloading. Thanks!